# How to differentiate the largest eigenvalue of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

Currently, I am facing the following problem.

Let $t \mapsto H (t)$ be a continuously differentiable, symmetric matrix-valued function. I would like to calculate the following derivative. Is there any general method to calculate it?$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} t} \lambda_{\max}(H(t))$$

Comment: Notice that in general $\lambda_{\textrm{max}}(H(t))$ need not exist for all $t$. For example, if $H(t) = \operatorname{diag}(t, -t)$ then $\lambda_{\textrm{max}}(H(t)) = |t|$, which is not differentiable at $t = 0$.

Comment: Hi Travis, thank you for pointing out this situation. If we constrain $H$ to be a positive definite matrix with distinct eigenvalues. Is there any way to analyze?

Comment: Implicit differentiation

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Consider the eigenvector $u$ associated with $\l=\l_{max}\,$ of
the matrix $\,H=H^T$

Start with the eigenvalue equation
$$\eqalign{
Hu = \l u \qif \c{u^TH=\l u^T} \\
}$$
Calculate the differential, multiply by $u^T$ and isolate $d\l$
$$\eqalign{
dH\:u + H\:du &= \l\:du + u\:d\l \\
u^TdH\:u + \c{u^TH}\,du &= \l\,{u^Tdu} + u^Tu\:d\l \\
u^TdH\:u + (\c{\l u^T}\,du) &= ({\l u^Tdu}) + u^Tu\:d\l \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
u^TdH\:u &= u^Tu\:d\l \qiq
\boxed{
\;d\l = \frac{u^TdH\:u}{u^Tu}\;\;\\
} \\
}$$
The time-derivative of $\l$ can be expressed in terms of
the time-derivative of $H$
$$\large\eqalign{
\dot\l &= \frac{u^T\dot H\:u}{u^Tu} \\
\ \\
}$$

Comment: hi Greg, thank you for the help! Your derivation is very clear.